# SwiftUI macOS menubar icon with badge

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, popover, nspopover

As you can see from the image I have a program that should open as `menubar`, I would like to know if it was possible to add a `badge` as seen in image two to the `menubar`, to indicate that there are `notifications`.

I find nothing on the documentation.

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

[image]

StatusBarController

```swift
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class StatusBarController {
    @ObservedObject var userPreferences = UserPreferences.instance
    private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem
    private var popover: NSPopover
    
    init(_ popover: NSPopover) {
        self.popover = popover
        statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            statusBarButton.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Fork")
            statusBarButton.image?.size = NSSize(width: 18.0, height: 18.0)
            statusBarButton.image?.isTemplate = true
            statusBarButton.action = #selector(togglePopover(sender:))
            statusBarButton.target = self
            statusBarButton.imagePosition = NSControl.ImagePosition.imageLeft
        }
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(popover.isShown) {
            hidePopover(sender)
        }else {
            showPopover(sender)
        }
    }
    
    func showPopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let statusBarButton = statusItem.button {
            popover.show(relativeTo: statusBarButton.bounds, of: statusBarButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        }
    }
    
    func hidePopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        popover.performClose(sender)
    }
    
}
```

AppDelegate

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    
    var timer: Timer? = nil

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView()
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 360, height: 360)
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: "I find nothing on the documentation"  Which type of notifications are you talking about, and what part of documentation are you reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it *manually*

Create a custom badge view. In `drawRect` you have to play with the position of the badge and the size of the number.

```
class BadgeView: NSView {
    
    var number : Int {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != number { needsDisplay = true }
        }
    }
    
    init(frame frameRect: NSRect, number : Int) {
        self.number = number
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.number = 0
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let fillColor = NSColor.systemRed
        let path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: NSRect(x: 3, y: 4, width: 14, height: 14))
        fillColor.set()
        path.fill()
        let one = "\(number)"
        let attribs : [NSAttributedString.Key:Any] = [.font : NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11.0), .foregroundColor : NSColor.white]
        let xOrigin = (number > 9) ? 3.5 : 6.5
        one.draw(at: NSPoint(x: xOrigin, y: 4.5), withAttributes: attribs)
    }
}
```

In the controller class add a property and a function to set the number

```
private var badgeView : BadgeView?

func setBadge(num : Int)
{
    if num == 0 {
        if let view = badgeView {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            badgeView = nil
        }
    } else {
        if let badgeView = badgeView {
            badgeView.number = num
        } else {
            badgeView = BadgeView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 19, height: 22), number: num)
            statusItem.button!.addSubview(badgeView!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I call it, for example in the ContentView in the Init function?
I tried this, but it fails: `self.StatusBarController.setBadge (num: 21)`

Comment: You need a reference to the real instance of `StatusBarController`. You could pass it to `ContentView`as a parameter

Comment: I did two tests:
1) Try calling it inside `AppDelegate` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`
So:
`statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
statusBar?.setBadge(num: 21)
`

Comment: As I said the code assumes that the badge image (the red circle) is in the asset catalog.

Comment: 2) Do such a thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1h6s.png
Create an instance and access it.

Comment: I edited the answer to draw the red circle directly.

Comment: Perfect so better, this is what I managed to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19mu9.png

But I would like to make sure that the badge color can be set as rgb color, example: `#2196f3`

As you can see from the image it is located in the lower left, it is possible to move it to the upper right.

Code: https://pastebin.com/8YhFi7UA

Comment: You have to play with the x and y positions. And you can use any color you want. `NSColor` has a variety of init methods

Comment: I understand, I more or less managed to make it work.
Can I ask you about some doubts that I am not being able to resolve?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not so familiar with SwiftUI

Comment: Exactly what this function part does: `badgeView = BadgeView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 26), number: num)
statusItem.button!.addSubview(badgeView!)`

Comment: It creates the badge view with the size w:30,h:26 and a default number value and adds it to the (sub)views of the button. The origin is irrelevant because it's being specified in the `drawRect` method.

Comment: But in the code it says: width: 19, height: 22

Comment: I don’t know the size of your badge, as I said initially you have to play with the size and the position.